# Problems with Codeigniter Session Class

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

this is my problem... I added to the construct of CI_Controller these lines

```
    $this->load->library("session");
    if($this->session->userdata("var")==FALSE)
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata("var", "value");   
    }
```

And when I use $this->session->userdata("var") in a child class, it doesn't have a value. I tested that by showing the value of $this->session->userdata("var") in the construct of CI_COntroller and in the construct of the child class and it shows me the value on the father but no on the child.

There is another thing, after reload the page about 3 or 4 times. It works very well.

I will be grateful for your answers. (And I'm sorry I'm not an English speaker)

Comment: Are you using cookies or storing in the database?

Comment: mmmm... I use the library session of codeigniter, does not it work with cookies?... I don't understand you

Comment: The Session library stores data in cookies by default, unless you set the config to use the database to store sessions.

Comment: oh I see... so I'm using cookies

Comment: Can you check Firebug or the Webkit console to see if you're getting a Set-Cookie response header on the request?

Comment: are you working on a localhost or webserver?

Comment: put the session library in autoload? It makes no sense that it works one place but not another, then it works after multiple page reloads...

Comment: Somewhat not related to the question, but modifying a core CodeIgniter class such as `CI_Controller` will make upgrades that much more difficult. You can probably achieve similar result with a custom library class that you auto-load.

Comment: are you sure you're calling `parent::__construct();` in the constructor?

Comment: set $foo = $this->session->userdata('var') and test if $foo is === false

Answer (score 1):

you should do

```
$this->load->library("session");
    if(!$this->session->userdata("var"))
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata("var", "value");   
    }
```

cause `userdata()` method returns false and true if isset or not session data.

Comment: Aren't `!$var` and `$var == FALSE` same expression?

Comment: @kidonchu anyway best practice is the one i showed u above in my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could have done it like this

```
$this->load->library("session");

$var    =   $this->session->userdata("var");

if(!$var)
{
    $this->session->set_userdata("var", "value");   
}
```